# Resize a specific table view cell depending on contentSize of UITextView

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, uitableview

I am trying to resize a specific `UITableViewCell` depending on the size of a `UITextView` - I have been trying for quite a while and seem to have absolutely no luck.

What I have done is calculate the size of the `UITextView` depending on its `contentSize` (which varies) and then returning the height within a `CGFloat` and then passing that the row height method and manipulating the height of it from there.

```
let contentSize = self.myTextView.sizeThatFits(self.myTextView.bounds.size)
var frame = self.myTextView.frame
frame.size.height = contentSize.height
self.myTextView.frame = frame

rowHeight = frame.height
```

I then have a `CGFloat` declared called rowHeight and then attempt to pass `contentSize.height` into it which seems to work but then the it doesn't change the size of the cell.

Here's the method:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat
{
    if (indexPath.section == 2 && indexPath.row == 0) {
        return rowHeight
    }
    else {
        return 44.0
    }
}
```

I have printed `frame.height.description` as a string in the console and then specifically defined it in the row height method and this works fine. This leads me to believe that my issue is calculating and placing the `CGFloat` within the rowHeight variable.

Can someone please guide me how to pass a `CGFloat` based on the size of a `UITextView` into a variable and then using that variable as the row height of a specific cell?

Comment: Have you tried reloading the table after you set rowHeight?

Comment: Try out these tutorial i think that could help you. http://useyourloaf.com/blog/self-sizing-table-view-cells.html and

http://www.raywenderlich.com/87975/dynamic-table-view-cell-height-ios-8-swift

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [apple's docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/reloadData)

> func reloadData()
>
> Call this method to reload all the data that is used to construct the
>   table, including cells, section headers and footers, index arrays, and
>   so on.

So this should redraw your table with the new height.